# Using mutually exclusive between groups

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to have a mutually exclusive group between different groups:
I have the arguments -a,-b,-c, and I want to have a conflict with -a and -b together, or -a and -c together. The help should show something like [-a | ([-b] [-c])].

The following code does not seem to do have mutually exclusive options:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My desc')
main_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
mysub_group = main_group.add_argument_group()
main_group.add_argument("-a", dest='a', action='store_true', default=False, help='a help')
mysub_group.add_argument("-b", dest='b', action='store_true',default=False,help='b help')
mysub_group.add_argument("-c", dest='c', action='store_true',default=False,help='c help')
parser.parse_args()
```

Parsing different combinations - all pass:

```
> python myscript.py -h
usage: myscript.py [-h] [-a] [-b] [-c]

My desc

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a          a help
> python myscript.py -a -c
> python myscript.py -a -b
> python myscript.py -b -c
```

I tried changing the `mysub_group` to be `add_mutually_exclusive_group` turns everything into mutually exclusive:

```
> python myscript.py -h
usage: myscript.py [-h] [-a | -b | -c]

My desc

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a          a help
  -b          b help
  -c          c help
```

How can I add arguments for [-a | ([-b] [-c])]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this has been asked a number of times. The simple answer is "with argparse, you can't". However, that's the simple answer. You could make use of subparsers, so:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My desc')
sub_parsers = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_a = sub_parsers.add_parser("a", help='a help')
parser_b = sub_parsers.add_parser("b", help='b help')
parser_b.add_argument("-c", dest='c', action='store_true',default=False,help='c help')
parser.parse_args()
```

You then get:

```
$ python parser -h
usage: parser [-h] {a,b} ...

My desc

positional arguments:
  {a,b}
    a         a help
    b         b help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

and:

```
$ python parser b -h
usage: parser b [-h] [-c]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -c          c help
```

If you would prefer your arguments as stated in the question, have a look at [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt), it looks lovely, and should do exactly what you want.

Comment: No quite what I want, as it does not gives me the option to just have -c (without the -b).

Comment: That's true, my apologies. I don't think you can get exactly what you want with argparse, but I still think docopt is a good choice, you'd just add 
    usage: myscript.py [ -h | -a | [-b -c]]
to your docstring and it'll work everything out for you

Answer (score 0):

`argument_groups` don't affect the parsing.  They just contribute to the help formatting.  So defining a group within an `mutually_exclusive_group` does not help with this problem.

There is a proposed patch, http://bugs.python.org/issue10984, `'argparse add_mutually_exclusive_group should accept existing arguments to register conflicts'`, that would allow you to define two `mutually_exclusive_groups`, one `[-a | -b]` and the other `[-a | -c]`.  Creating a 2nd group that includes an argument (`-a`) that is already defined is the trivial part of this patch.  Producing a meaningful usage line is more difficult, and required a rewrite of several `HelpFormatter` methods.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My desc')
group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
action_a = group1.add_argument("-a", dest='a', action='store_true', default=False, help='a help')
group1.add_argument("-b", dest='b', action='store_true',default=False,help='b help')

group2 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group2.add_argument("-c", dest='c', action='store_true',default=False,help='c help')
group2._group_actions.append(action_a) # THE KLUDGE

print parser.format_usage() 
# usage: stack16769409.py [-h] [-a | -b] [-c] 

args  = parser.parse_args()
```

`Usage` does not show the 2 groups correctly.  But it does accept `-b -c`, while objecting to `-a -b` and `-a -c`.  But you can write a custom usage line.