# How to add optional or once arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

How can I add an argument that is optional and must not be specified multiple times?

Valid:

```
$ ./my.py
$ ./my.py --arg MyArgValue
```

Invalid:

```
$ ./my.py --arg MyArgValue --arg ThisIsNotValid
```

If I add an argument like:

```
parser.add_argument('--arg', type=str)
```

The invalid example results in a string `ThisIsNotValid`. I would expect a parser error.

Comment: On my python installation (2.7) I don't get a list with one element (`['ThisIsNotValid']`) but a string (`'ThisIsNotValid'`) when I copy and paste your code.

Comment: Correct: edited questions.

Comment: Why might your user use this option more than once?  The default behavior of argparse is to allow the use of flags in any order, that includes repeating them.  But other than with `count` and `append` actions, repeating is of little use - except to possibly correct an earlier use.

Comment: @hpaulj: by mistake. I found myself troubleshooting a script for hours because of that. I personally don't see a meaningful use case for this argparse behavior of overriding previously specified options.

Comment: fyi, usually people expect `--arg` with two dashes for arguments that are not just a single char.

Comment: argparse just works through the argument strings.  If it finds a `-o` string it tries to take the action specified to that string.  If it encounters that string again, it does the same thing, without referring to a record of what it did before.  This is convenient for `count` and `append` actions, but not convenient in your case.  It does, though, keep track of which positionals it has processed.  But those are 'no-name' arguments that have to occur in a particular order with no repeats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom action that raises an exception if the same argument is seen twice. When the parser catches the exception, it prints the usage and a nicely-formatted error message.

```
import argparse

class Highlander(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if getattr(namespace, self.dest, None) is not None:
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, 'There can be only one.')
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', action=Highlander)
print (parser.parse_args('-f 1 -f 2'.split()))
```

Comment: Cool, this seems to be the most elegant solution so far!

Comment: If you don't want to depend on the `default` being `None`, you could store a custom counter or flag in the namespace, e.g. `setattr(namespace, self.dest+'used', True)`, and test for that.

Comment: I hate to say it, but this is definitely better than my solution.

Comment: As @hpaulj said, this only works if there is no default value.  Fixing the check in the `__call__` , we can fix this: Change:`if getattr(namespace, self.dest, None) is not None`     to     `if (self.default is not None and self.default != getattr(namespace, self.dest, None)) or (self.default is None and getattr(namespace, self.dest, None) is not None)`

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a hacky solution, but will get you what you want.  Use the `append` [action](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#action):

```
parser.add_argument('-arg', type=str, action='append')
args = parser.parse_args()
if len(args.arg) > 1:
    sys.exit("Only one argument is allowed for '-arg'")
elif len(args.arg) == 1: # elif is because it is valid for the length to be 0
    args.arg = args.arg[0]
```

The append action will create a list from the command line consisting of all the values from all the times this argument was called.  If the length of this list is longer than one, there was an error.

This way you can get the values from the command line, and if there are more than one you can catch this as an error and notify the user.

Comment: I understand that I can write code to check this. Simplest way would be to check whether args.myarg is an array. I was hoping that there is a more elegant way, since this seems to me such a simple use case.

Comment: @Alex Actually, without the 'append' action you just get the last value for a given option (not a list), so there is no way to know if the user gave the option more than once.  At least in this case you can tell if it was given multiple times and catch that as an error.

Comment: Just debugged that again: a list with one element, the value of the last argument. Not very intuitive behavior of argparse, I guess. Python 2.7 though.

Comment: @Alex I don't get a list if I don't use `action='append'`.

Comment: you're right, I messed up my test harness playing around with other options :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get the number of occurences with this, and yield an error if it is more than one.

> 'append' - This stores a list, and appends each argument value to the list. This is useful to allow an option to be specified multiple times. Example usage:

```
import argparse
import sys
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-arg', type='str', action='append')
args = parser.parse_args()
if len(args.arg) > 1:
    sys.exit('Invalid')
MyArgValue = args.arg[0]
```

The documentation about 'append' can be found in here for further details:

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action

Unfortunately, there is no simpler way with argparse. That is presumably because this is not a common use case enough. Usually, this count is used for boolean cases, like the verbose mode. When you have appending strings, like compilers with the include path, and so forth, they are usually all respected.

Perhaps, you could also use nargs and just use args.arg_name[0] and ignore the rest. Here you can find the `nargs` documentation for that:

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#nargs

Comment: I still need the actual value "MyArgValue", not the count.

Comment: Yes, very similar to what Seth posted first.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested a solution that uses a `mutually_exclusive_group`.  The idea is to define a group that includes `--arg` twice.  The parser maintains a `seen_non_default_actions` list, and checks that for exclusive group conflicts before taking action on a new argument string.  If `--arg` is already present in this list, the next call would conflict with it, and raise an error.

There are couple of problems with this approach.

1) existing actions cannot be added to a new mutually_exclusive_group.  In https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555236/901925 I illustrate a kludge that gets around that.  It also cites a proposed patch that makes this easier.

2) currently `parse_args` adds the action to the `seen_non_default_actions` list, and then checks for conflicts.  This means the first `--arg` will conflict with itself.  The solution is to switch the order.  First check for conflicts, then add the action to the list.

```
import my_argparse as argparse  # use a customized argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="PROG",
    formatter_class=argparse.MultiGroupHelpFormatter)
# use a custom formatter than can handle overlapping groups

action = parser.add_argument('--arg', help='use this argument only once')
# define a group with two copies of this action as per patch issue10984
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(action, action)
args  = parser.parse_args()
```

When called with various arguments, produces:

```
$ python3 test.py -h
usage: PROG [-h] [--arg ARG | --arg ARG]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --arg ARG   use this argument only once

$ python3 test.py --arg test
Namespace(arg='test')

$ python3 test.py --arg test --arg next
usage: PROG [-h] [--arg ARG | --arg ARG]
PROG: error: argument --arg: not allowed with argument --arg
```

I am wonder, though, whether this is a sufficiently intuitive way of saying, 'use this argument only once'.  Does the usage line `[--arg ARG | --arg ARG]` convey that?  And is the error message `argument --arg: not allowed with argument --arg` clear enough?