# Python argparse with nargs behaviour incorrect

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

Here is my argparse sample say sample.py

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", nargs="+", help="Stuff")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

Python - 2.7.3

I expect that the user supplies a list of arguments separated by spaces after the -p option. For example, if you run

```
$ sample.py -p x y 
Namespace(p=['x', 'y'])
```

But my problem is that when you run

```
$ sample.py -p x -p y
Namespace(p=['y'])
```

Which is neither here nor there. I would like one of the following

- Throw an exception to the user asking him to not use -p twice instead just supply them as one argument
- Just assume it is the same option and produce a list of ['x','y'].

I can see that python 2.7 is doing neither of them which confuses me. Can I get python to do one of the two behaviours documented above?

Comment: You certainly *can* get it to do what you want by subclassing `argparse.Action`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: python 3.8 adds an `action="extend"` which will create the desired list of ['x','y']

To produce a list of ['x','y'] use `action='append'`.  Actually it gives

```
Namespace(p=[['x'], ['y']])
```

For each `-p` it gives a list `['x']` as dictated by `nargs='+'`, but `append` means, add that value to what the Namespace already has.  The default action just sets the value, e.g. `NS['p']=['x']`.  I'd suggest reviewing the `action` paragraph in the docs.

`optionals` allow repeated use by design.  It enables actions like `append` and `count`.  Usually users don't expect to use them repeatedly, or are happy with the last value.  `positionals` (without the `-flag`) cannot be repeated (except as allowed by `nargs`).

[How to add optional or once arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544468/how-to-add-optional-or-once-arguments/18564559#18564559)  has some suggestions on how to create a 'no repeats' argument.  One is to create a custom `action` class.

Comment: It is a pity that this is not available by default... sigh

Comment: Do you have suggestions on how to specify 'only allow one use of this option'?  How would it be marked on the usage line?

Comment: I would have thought that is the default i.e, being able to specify an option only once. I see your point though, all linux commands are able to take the same option multiple times so am not too sure what to compare it with.

Comment: But there is an inherent problem if the developer forgot to do nargs=+ the argparse simply assumes the latest definition of a variable. There probably isn't an easy answer to this. I will try some linux commands on how they handle same option being specified multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I decided to go with the custom action route as suggested by mgilson.

```
import argparse
class ExtendAction(argparse.Action):
  def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
    if getattr(namespace, self.dest, None) is None:
      setattr(namespace, self.dest, [])
    getattr(namespace, self.dest).extend(values)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", nargs="+", help="Stuff", action=ExtendAction)
args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

This results in

```
$ ./sample.py -p x -p y -p z w
Namespace(p=['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'])
```

Still, it would have been much neater if there was an `action='extend'` option in the library by default.

Comment: If you are subclassing your ArgumentParser, it might be convenient to 'register' your custom class.  See the `_ActionsContainer` class.