# Python argparse : how to detect duplicated optional argument?

Tags: python, argparse, option-type

I'm using argparse with optional parameter, but I want to avoid having something like this : script.py -a 1 -b -a 2
Here we have twice the optional parameter 'a', and only the second parameter is returned. I want either to get both values or get an error message.
How should I define the argument ?

[Edit]
This is the code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', dest='alpha', action='store', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('-b', dest='beta', action='store', nargs='?')

params, undefParams = self.parser.parse_known_args()
```

Comment: Show us the code you have so far, otherwise we can and will not help you ...

Comment: Try https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

Comment: I've added the code. But this link is not helping. I don't want an option to be specified twice. Current this is what is happening :
script.py -a 1 -b 2 -a 3  ---> gives a=3 and b=2 without error and no info on the first param. I just want to consider having same optional parameter twice as error.

Comment: Yes, at the very least, issuing a warning would be helpful.  Looks like just another argparse deficiency. :-(

Answer (score 7):

`append` action will collect the values from repeated use in a list

```
parser.add_argument('-a', '--alpha', action='append')
```

producing an `args` namespace like:

```
namespace(alpha=['1','3'], b='4')
```

After parsing you can check `args.alpha`, and accept or complain about the number of values.  `parser.error('repeated -a')` can be used to issue an argparse style error message.

You could implement similar functionality in a custom Action class, but that requires understanding the basic structure and operation of such a class.  I can't think anything that can be done in an Action that can't just as well be done in the appended list after.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23032953/901925 is an answer with a no-repeats custom `Action`.

Why are you using `nargs='?'` with flagged arguments like this?  Without a `const` parameter this is nearly useless (see the `nargs=?` section in the docs).

Another similar SO: [Python argparse with nargs behaviour incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228516/python-argparse-with-nargs-behaviour-incorrect)