# argparse: flatten the result of action='append'

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to make a script that supports an argument list of the form

```
./myscript --env ONE=1,TWO=2 --env THREE=3
```

Here's my attempt:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '--env',
    type=lambda s: s.split(','),
    action='append',
)
options = parser.parse_args()
print options.env

$ ./myscript --env ONE=1,TWO=2 --env THREE=3
[['ONE=1', 'TWO=2'], ['THREE=3']]
```

Sure I can fix this in postprocessing:

```
options.env = [x for y in options.env for x in y]
```

but I'm wondering if there's some way to get the flattened list directly from argparse, so that I don't have to maintain a list of "things I need to flatten afterwards" in my head as I'm adding new options to the program.

The same question applies if I were to use `nargs='*'` instead of `type=lambda...`.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '--env',
    nargs='+',
    action='append',
)
options = parser.parse_args()
print options.env

$ ./myscript --env ONE=1 TWO=2 --env THREE=3
[['ONE=1', 'TWO=2'], ['THREE=3']]
```

Comment: Found some workarounds over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228516/python-argparse-with-nargs-behaviour-incorrect but nothing I'd actually use in production code.

Comment: What's your criteria for using a workaround in production code?

Answer (score 32):

**Edit:** [*Since Python 3.8, the "extend" is available directly in stdlib*](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#action). If you only have to support 3.8+ then defining it yourself is no longer required. Usage of stdlib "extend" action is exactly the same way as this answer originally described:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> _ = parser.add_argument('--env', nargs='+', action='extend')
>>> parser.parse_args(["--env", "ONE", "TWO", "--env", "THREE"])
Namespace(env=['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'])
```

---

Unfortunately, there isn't an `extend` action provided in `ArgumentParser` by default.  But it's not too hard to register one:

```
import argparse

class ExtendAction(argparse.Action):

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        items = getattr(namespace, self.dest) or []
        items.extend(values)
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, items)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.register('action', 'extend', ExtendAction)
parser.add_argument('--env', nargs='+', action='extend')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Demo:

```
$ python /tmp/args.py --env one two --env three
Namespace(env=['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

The `lambda` you have in your example is somewhat outside the intended use-case of the `type` kwarg.  So, I would recommend instead to split on whitespace, because it will be a pain to correctly handle the case where `,` is actually in the data.  If you split on space, you get this functionality for free:

```
$ python /tmp/args.py --env one "hello world" two --env three
Namespace(env=['one', 'hello world', 'two', 'three'])
```

Answer (score 2):

An `extend` action class has been asked for (http://bugs.python.org/issue23378), but since it's easy to add your own I don't think the feature will ever by added.

A common Python idiom for flattening a list uses `chain`:

```
In [36]: p=[['x'], ['y']]
In [37]: from itertools import chain
In [38]: chain(*p)
Out[38]: <itertools.chain at 0xb17afb2c>
In [39]: list(chain(*p))
Out[39]: ['x', 'y']
```

Your list comprehension is the equivalent:

```
In [40]: [x for y in p for x in y]
Out[40]: ['x', 'y']
```

In http://bugs.python.org/issue16399#msg277919 I suggest another possiblity - a custom `default` value for the `append` argument.

```
class MyList(list):
    def append(self,arg):
        if isinstance(arg,list):
            self.extend(arg)
        else:
            super(MyList, self).append(arg)

 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 a = parser.add_argument('-f', action='append', nargs='*',default=MyList([]))
 args = parser.parse_args('-f 1 2 3 -f 4 5'.split())
```

which produces

```
Namespace(f=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
```

You'll have to use your own judgment as to what's appropriate in production code.

Comment: Merged in 3.8. Just needed the [hat tip from Guido](https://bugs.python.org/issue23378#msg342952), it seems.

Comment: For people not yet on 3.8, there's `chain.from_iterable()` which makes the workaround clearer and hopefully more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one that solves but not directly from argparse

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '--env',
    nargs='+',
    action='append',
)
options = parser.parse_args()

options.env = [item for args in options.env for item in args]

print options.env
```

Output is this:

> $ ./argtest.py --env ONE=1 TWO=2 --env THREE=3
>
> ['ONE=1', 'TWO=2', 'THREE=3']

Comment: How is this different from the list comprehension part of hpaulj's answer?