# argparse funneling positional arguments into multiple lists

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to be able to support positional command line arguments that go into different lists based on prior predicates.

For example, a command like:

```
mycommand one two three
```

would yield args like:

```
main_dest = ['one','two','three']
other_dest = []
```

but a command like:

```
mycommand one --other two three --main four five
```

would yield args like:

```
main_dest = ['one','four','five']
other_dest = ['two','three']
```

Conceptually what I'd like is an action that modifies the `dest` of the positional argument reader.

Answer (score 2):

As a first try this set of Actions seems to do the trick:

```
In [73]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [74]: parser.add_argument('main', nargs='*');
In [75]: parser.add_argument('other', nargs='*');
In [76]: parser.add_argument('--main', action='append');
In [77]: parser.add_argument('--other', action='append');

In [78]: parser.print_usage()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--main MAIN] [--other OTHER]
                [main [main ...]] [other [other ...]]

In [79]: parser.parse_args('one two three'.split())
Out[79]: Namespace(main=['one', 'two', 'three'], other=[])

In [80]: parser.parse_args('one --other two --main three'.split())
Out[80]: Namespace(main=['one', 'three'], other=['two'])
```

74 and 76 both have `main` as their `dest`.  I use `append` for the flagged ones so they don't overwrite positional values.  But despite what the `usage` shows, positionals will only work at the start.  If placed a the end they'll overwrite flagged values.  And the 'other' positional will never get values - so I should have omitted it.

So it is possible to play games like this, but I'm not sure it's robust, or any easier for your users.

[argparse: flatten the result of action='append'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152799/argparse-flatten-the-result-of-action-append)

Comment: I edited my question to make it a bit more clear that I wanted possibly multiple arguments to follow the stream split. I had tried that solution before and unfortunately even adding `nargs` to the `main` and `other` parameters didn't actually help (IIRC I got a list-of-lists result or something similarly weird).

Comment: You can flatten lists of lists latter. You could also write variation on the append action that used list extend.  Other customizations of action class might also be needed.  Other SO argparse answers have customized the Action class in various ways.