# argparse mutually_exclusive_group with sub groups

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to make a script with usage as follows:

```
my_script [-p parg -l larg] | [-s sarg]
```

i.e the script either takes `-p` and `-l` argument **OR** `-s` argument. It is an error if both `-p` and `-s` are specified. I tried the following but doesn't seem to work

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some Desc')
gp = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
num_gp = gp.add_argument_group()
num_gp.add_argument('-p')
num_gp.add_argument('-l')
gp.add_argument('-s')
In [18]: parser.parse_args(['-p blahp', '-l blahl', '-s blahs'])
Out[18]: Namespace(l=' blahl', p=' blahp', s=' blahs') #ERROR Should have failed as I specify both `-p` and `-s` which belong to a mutually_exclusive_group
```

Comment: Hey, if you've got the freedom, try out `docopt` instead of argparse.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769409/using-mutually-exclusive-between-groups/

Comment: Is `-l` required with `-p`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misusing the mutually exclusive groups. Groups are not mutually exclusive with other groups, members of a group are mutually exclusive with each other. Also, as far as I can tell from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argument-groups), standard groups do not affect parsing logic, they only help to organize the help message generated by the parser.

Here is how you could make two options, `-p` and `-s` for example, mutually exclusive:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some Desc')
group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group1.add_argument("-p")
group1.add_argument("-s")

# This works
args = parser.parse_args(["-p", "argForP"])
# This will throw an error
args = parser.parse_args(["-p", "argForP", "-s", "argForS"])
```

But I'm not sure if this functionality will allow you to implement your use case because I'm not sure that an argument can belong to two mutually exclusive groups. However you can always do error checking yourself, and use `parser.error`. That would look something like this:

```
message = "invalid options"

# Tells us p is used without l or vise versa
if (args.p is None) != (args.l is None):
    parser.error(message)

# Tells is if p-l is used with s
if (args.p is None) == (args.s is None):
    # Either both are used or neigher
    parser.error(message)
```

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue10984  has a patch that allows you to put an argument in two different mutually exclusive groups.  Adding an argument to a 2nd group isn't that tricky, but getting a meaningful usage line requires rewriting a good chunk of the help formatting code.

Comment: You are right.  Regular groups affect the help display, but have no effect when parsing.

Comment: @hpaulj, Nice work, it seems like even when I run across a bug or wart in python someone is already working on fixing it. It's nice to see the community is so active. Jut to clarify for the OP (and for me), the patch you linked to in your comment has not made it into the latest release right? If someone wanted to use this new functionality they'd need to apply the patch to their python installation. Is that correct?

Comment: There are a number of proposed patches for argparse that have not been approved or applied.  Issues that have been applied will have a message from someone like 'Author: Roundup Robot (python-dev)'.